# Macro fails in Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word macro that has been working fine for ages. I have recently upgraded to Word 2013 and the behavior has changed.

It occurs on the following line:

```
        Doc.SaveAs Path + "Manual\" + TitleString + ".htm", wdFormatFilteredHTML
```

which builds a valid file path and name and saves the current document as an HTML page.

Under Word 2013, the macro opens a file save dialog box with no filename and with the default file extension (.docx) instead of (.htm), as if the filtered HTML mode was no more available.

I have tried with named arguments, and also with the new SaveAs2 method, but saw no change.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I'd try turning on the Macro Recorder and saving it and seeing what you get. Also, it's not the source of this problems, but I'd use "&" instead of "+" for concatenation.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. To my great surprise, a SaveAs operation is not recorded at all ! Only Save is (but this is not what I need :( )

Comment: Reading back over your question and looking at the online help I can't think of anything that you haven't already addressed. Well, one thing maybe, which is to try it with another brand new document.

Comment: Thanks for the hand, this was impossible to troubleshoot by human means...

Answer (score 0):

I fond this comment on the DataZX.CN forum:"I Had the same problem. I'm running a windows 8/64bits on an ACER laptop. SOLUTION : remove the Add-in "Icloud Acer ...".

I happen to use Acer desktop, and there was indeed this Icloud add-in pre-installed in Word. After disabling it, the macro works !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks StackOverflow for pointing me in the right direction as always...
   and thanks Yves for spreading the info...

I removed Acer cloud plugin from Word and excel just to be on safe side.

Blame foolish manufacturers like Acer for another bundled piece of crap software that causes more harm than good.

Quoted from MSDN forum post...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/59c0da80-a7e6-4026-855c-f6b9fbf9c386/word-2013-vba-documentsaveas-dialog-appears-even-applicationclassdisplayalerts-?forum=worddev

...From all you tell me, my feeling is that there may be another third-party application (or a virus) mixing in - that the display of SaveAs is not coming from your application.

This is difficult for you to test, since whatever it is is probably loading with Word...